# How to maintaining an model object across different fragments Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Is there any good way to maintain an java object which will be common across my fragments ? Scenario is as defined as below :

An common activity `MainActivity` which holds all the fragments :

1] `Master Fragment` (Container fragment),
2] Two fragments `A` & `B` in view pager in bottom half of `Master Fragment`,

All this arangment is for getting user profile details,

`Fragment A` gets some basic infomation like name, age, DOB, gender etc. then `Fragment B` gets infromation about contact like mobile, email, address etc.

The master fragment has the main object which is of model class `UserInfo.java`, I have created new object of `userInfo` in `Master Fragment`, `Fragment A` & `B` have the actual `EditBoxes` which will take values to be written to this `userInfo` object. So can I maintain a common object with live state (i.e. Update in any edit box should reflect into corresponding field of `userInfo` object). I want to maintain this common object userInfo across three fragmnents i.e. `MasterFragment, A` & `B` ? How do I do it, (Without static field) ?

Comment: You can create a variable in Activity class and refer to it from Fragments with `((MainActivity) getActivity()).userInfo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a common `UserInfo` instance in the `MainActivity` instance and provide access for all fragments through `Fragment.getActivity()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private UserInfo userInfo;

    public getCommonUserInfo() {
         if (userInfo == null) {
             userInfo = new UserInfo();
         }
         return userInfo;
    }

}
```

then from any fragment:

```
((MainActivity) this.getActivity()).getCommonUserInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating Userinfo object in Master fragment create **static** object in Parent Activity (MainActivity).